# how do i make a "date picker form validate" and only accept inputs that are two months ahead

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

i am making a booking form  and i need my clients to know that they can only select dates two months of ahead of the current day , how do i make my form do that?

```
<form class="form js-step-form form--stacked form--full-width" novalidate="novalidate" action="form2.html" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="74uJISV+9itpMIkGoDY4r2o9beGrLyTV735R0fjIm6kzWT8rLry/7mSxZRj40vHAw8MXjg9WlcC+7p9y6eIDVQ=" />
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="move_in" />
      <input value="Website" type="hidden" name="rental_application[source]" id="rental_application_source" />
      <input type="hidden" name="rental_application[guest_card_uid]" id="rental_application_guest_card_uid" />
      <input type="hidden" name="listable_uid" id="listable_uid" value="529f9fcd-b5fc-478f-8c5b-44fbec44f051" />

    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid__medium-6 grid__small-12">
        <div class="form__row"><label class="form__row__label" for="rental_application_desired_move_in">Minimum Move-in Date</label><div class="form__row__body"><div class="form__row__field-wrapper"><div class="js-gears-date input-add-on"><input class="js-datepicker js-move-in-gears-date" type="text" value="07/01/2019" name="rental_application[desired_move_in]" id="rental_application_desired_move_in" /><span class="js-datepicker-trigger input-add-on__append button"><span class="icon icon-calendar"></span></span></div></div></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>


        <div class="js-applicant-type-radio-buttons">
          <input type="hidden" name="applicant_type[applicant_type]" value="" /><div class="form__row u-space-bs"><label for="applicant_type_applicant_type_0"><input type="radio" value="0" checked="checked" name="applicant_type[applicant_type]" id="applicant_type_applicant_type_0" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="applicant_type_applicant_type_0">I am applying as a <strong>tenant</strong>. (I will be living on the property.)</label></label></div><div class="form__row u-space-bs"><label for="applicant_type_applicant_type_1"><input type="radio" value="1" name="applicant_type[applicant_type]" id="applicant_type_applicant_type_1" /><label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="applicant_type_applicant_type_1">I am applying as a <strong>co-signer/guarantor</strong> for another applicant. (I will not be living on the property.)</label></label></div>
        </div>           
<button onclick="myFunction()">Start Application</button>
```

i expect users to receive an error message saying they have to select a date two months ahead of their current date, and users that pick dates two months ahead should move forward

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make a good use of https://momentjs.com/
This will allow you to do things like: `moment().add(60, 'days').calendar();`